# UnsatisfiedLinkError when init skmap on some devices

Tags: android, skmaps

I develop application that use SKmaps and it run fine
on my Nexus 5, Nexus 6, Note 8 And Asus Fonepad 7

but when i call

```
new SKPrepareMapTextureThread(this, mapResDirPath, "SKMaps.zip", this).start();
```

On LG G4 And Huawei Ascend Mate 7 then the application force close and in logcat show

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.moveplus.jeenja-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.moveplus.jeenja-1/lib/arm64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libngnative.so"
>          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:378)
>          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:998)
>          at com.skobbler.ngx.SKMaps.(SourceFile:59)
>          at com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread.a(SourceFile:130)
>          at com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread.run(SourceFile:86)

I have put SKMaps.jar into libs folder and SKMaps.zip in assets folder
And all .so file in jniLibs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8UnH.png

Did i just do something wrong

**Edit**

According to @chiragjn comment i try to look in my apk file and found this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXbCC.png

arm64-v8a generated by other like Realm libs so when application start it just looking for libngnative.so in arm64-v8a folder and not found,then i change Realm build from gradle to jar and remove lib/arm64-v8a and lib/mips from Realm jar file and add to my project and then try to run again and UnsatisfiedLinkError gone

Comment: Seems like your apk is missing the file "libngnative.so".  Just perform a check with filemanager and look for the file "libngnative.so" at /vendor/lib64 and /system/lib64 in all the phones, probably G4 and Ascend Mate won't have it.

Comment: @chiragjin Thank you for your reply, i just look in my apk file and then i realise that i use Realm in my project and yes Realm generate arm64-v8a folder so i remove this folder and try to install from sdcard and it's work